# Search phrases and terms (stored in a file) in a text article

Tags: bash, unix, search, text, pattern-matching

I have two text files, one containing keywords and phrases (file1.txt) and a paragraph-based text file (file2.txt). I'm trying to find the keywords/phrases in file1.txt that appeared on file2.txt

Here's a sample data:

File 1 (file1.txt):

```
123 111 1111
ABC 000
A 999
B 000
C 111
Thank you
```

File 2 (file2.txt)

```
Hello!

The following order was completed: ABC 000
Item 1 (A 999)
Item 2 (X 412)
Item 3 (8 357)

We will call: 123 111 1111 if we encounter any issues

Thank you very much!
```

Desired output:

```
123 111 1111
ABC 000
A 999
Thank you
```

I've tried the grep command:

```
grep -Fxf file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

And I'm getting a blank output.txt

What suggestions do you have to get the right output?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
grep -o -f file1.txt  <file2.txt
```

`-o` < print only matching pattern
`-f` < search for this string line by line
`<`  < Standard input

Demo :

```
$cat file1.txt 
123 111 1111
ABC 000
A 999
B 000
C 111
Thank you
$cat file2.txt 
Hello!

The following order was completed: ABC 000
Item 1 (A 999)
Item 2 (X 412)
Item 3 (8 357)

We will call: 123 111 1111 if we encounter any issues

Thank you very much!
$grep -o -f file1.txt  <file2.txt 
ABC 000
A 999
123 111 1111
Thank you
$
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the contents of file1.txt as output:

123 111 1111
ABC 000
A 999
B 000
C 111
Thank you

Comment: `grep -o -f file1.txt  <file2.txt  > output.txt` if you want to save the output in file

Comment: The desired file should only contain the keywords/phrases that appear on the paragraph text file. So it should not contain the terms "B 000" and "C 111".